# How to find time and space complexity for this code?

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have implemented a code to construct pattern count tree. How do i find its time and space complexity?

```
class PCTree
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
 BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 int n;//No of Patterns
 int f;//No of Features
 float initial_no_of_nodes=0;//No of Nodes in Input Patterns
 float final_no_of_nodes=0;//No of Nodes in PC Tree(Output)
 float compression_rate;//percentage compression

 System.out.println("Enter No of Patterns:");
 n=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

 //2-D array to store Features
 int pattern[][]= new int[n][20];

//No of Features for each Pattern
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)//NO of Features for each Pattern
 { 
     System.out.println("Enter No of Features for Pattern "+(i+1)+" : ");
     f=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
     pattern[i]=new int[f];
 }

//Features of each pattern
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    System.out.println("Enter Features for Pattern "+(i+1)+" : ");
    for(int j=0;j<pattern[i].length;j++)
    {
    pattern[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
    }
 }


 System.out.println("==============");
 System.out.println("INPUT ");
 System.out.println("==============");

//Print Features of each pattern
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {

    for(int j=0;j<pattern[i].length;j++)
    {
    System.out.print(" "+pattern[i][j]+" ");
    initial_no_of_nodes++;
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
 System.out.println("\nNODES: "+initial_no_of_nodes);//Print Initial No of Nodes
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println();
 System.out.println("==============");
 System.out.println("PC TREE ");
 System.out.println("==============");

 //Construction of PC Tree
 //Print First Pattern as it is
 for(int j=0;j<pattern[0].length;j++)
    {
    System.out.print(" "+pattern[0][j]+" ");
    final_no_of_nodes++;
    }
    System.out.println();

    int i=0;//processing pattern
    int k=0;//processing features
    int j=1;//processing pattern


while((i<=(n-1))&&(j<n))//Loop works till last pattern is processed  
{   
   inner: //performs matching of Features
   while(k<pattern[j].length)
    {
    if (pattern[i][k]==pattern[j][k])//Equal Prefix Found
        {
        System.out.print(" _ ");//Print "Blank" Indicate sharing
        k++;
        }
    else//Prefix not equal
     {

        for(int p=k;p<pattern[j].length;p++)//print all features(suffix) 
        {
        System.out.print(" "+pattern[j][p]+" ");
        final_no_of_nodes++;
        }
        i++;//next pattern
        j++;//next pattern
        k=0;//start again from first feature
        break inner;//go to next pattern
     }
    }
    System.out.println();

}   
 System.out.println("\nNODES: "+final_no_of_nodes);
 compression_rate=((initial_no_of_nodes-final_no_of_nodes)/initial_no_of_nodes)*100;
 System.out.println();  
 System.out.println("COMPRESSION RATE: "+compression_rate);  
}
```

}

How do i find its time and space complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity would be as follows

1. O(1) for each initialization
2. O(n) for each loop
3. O(n^2) for each nested loop
4. O(n^3) for if condition within nested loop

For this part of code

```
 BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 int n;//No of Patterns
 int f;//No of Features
 float initial_no_of_nodes=0;//No of Nodes in Input Patterns
 float final_no_of_nodes=0;//No of Nodes in PC Tree(Output)
 float compression_rate;//percentage compression

 System.out.println("Enter No of Patterns:");
 n=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

 //2-D array to store Features
 int pattern[][]= new int[n][20];
```

Complexity would be simply the no of statements while initialization

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    System.out.println("Enter Features for Pattern "+(i+1)+" : ");
    for(int j=0;j<pattern[i].length;j++)
 {
    pattern[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
    }
  }
```

Complexity would be O(n^2)

```
for(int j=0;j<pattern[0].length;j++)
    {
    System.out.print(" "+pattern[0][j]+" ");
    final_no_of_nodes++;
    }
```

Complexity would be O(n)

```
while((i<=(n-1))&&(j<n))//Loop works till last pattern is processed  
{   
   inner: //performs matching of Features
   while(k<pattern[j].length)
    {
    if (pattern[i][k]==pattern[j][k])//Equal Prefix Found
        {
        System.out.print(" _ ");//Print "Blank" Indicate sharing
        k++;
        }
```

Complexity would be O(n^3)

and the complexity for the statements other then these would have complexity O(1) each

so the complexity would be as n+n^2+n^3

so using condition n^3 >> n and also n^3 >> n^2 complexity will be **O(n^3)**

Space complexity can be calculated using

```
Type        Typical Bit Width   
char            1byte       
unsigned char   1byte        
signed char     1byte       
int             4bytes      
unsigned int    4bytes  
signed int      4bytes  
short int       2bytes  
long int        4bytes
```

Comment: I don't think the if statements take time proportional to the size of the input (n). In fact, the values for k can go from 0 to 19, not from 0 to n. So the time spent in the innermost loop (defined indirectly via the if) is at most 20, i.e., O(1) from the asymptotic complexity point of view. So the complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: Have a reference for this sagar?

Answer (score 0):

The construct `while((i<=(n-1))&&(j<n))` defines two nested loops. Each iterates at most n times, so they take O(n^2)*T'(n) where T'(n) is the time taken by the innermost loop defined by the `while(k<pattern[j].length)` statement.

The innermost loop executes at most `pattern[j].length` times and has to different branches, one that takes constant time, the other another nested loop that executes at most `pattern[j].length` as well. That means the time taken by the inner loop is at most 20*20 = 400, i.e., T'(n) = O(400) = O(1), since it's a constant that, I assume, does not depend on the size of the input n.

Thus the asymptotic complexity for the whole algorithm is O(n^2).

However, looking at your code, this looks suspicious:

```
int pattern[][]= new int[n][20];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
  System.out.println("Enter No of Features for Pattern "+(i+1)+" : ");
  f=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
  pattern[i]=new int[f];
}
```

You first define each array `pattern[i]` as having size 20 and then allow the user to redefine it. That means it could be bigger than 20 and my analysis would not work. In fact, if the maximum number of features entered by the user is m, the asymptotic time is O(m*n^2) instead. Now if m = O(1) (a small constant), this formula reduces to the previous one. However, if m = O(n) (proportional to the number of patterns), then the complexity becomes cubic as noted in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity for a more formal description of time complexity. Basically, you need to count the number of elementary operations. In this case, you just need to calculate the number of iterations in your loops.

Your first `for` loop has `n` iterations (`O(n)`). Your second and third loops have `n*20` iterations (`n` for the outer loop and `20` for the inner), giving `O(2*(n*20)) = O(n)`. The fourth loop is `20` iterations, which is simply `O(1)`. Worst case, the last loop has `n*39` iterations, giving `O(n)` again. So your time complexity is

```
 O(n) + O(n) + O(1) + O(n) = O(n)
```

Calculating the space complexity is a bit trickier. It depends on the scope. You basically just count the size of each variable, but you'd need to know the size of a `BufferedReader` object.